# Grid, why won’t the columns start on the same row?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Hope some can explain why the columns in the grid don’t start on the same row. I have set both the columns to start on row 2, but the ul-list container (aside) start below, and the image-boxs start where it should.

**This is what i want**:

```
—————   —————————————                          
Ul()     Img()  Img()
Li       <p>    <p>
Li       Img()  Img()
Li       <p>    <p>
```

**This is happen:**

```
—————   —————————————                          
         Img()  Img()
         <p>    <p>
Ul()     Img()  Img()
Li       <p>    <p>
Li       
Li
```

**Putting my HTML-code under here:**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="headline1">
        <h2>Filter</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="headline2">
        <h2>Prosjekter</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="aside_container">
        <div class="aside1">
            <h3>Vakker:</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>1 Helhetlig utforming</li>
                <li>2 Estetisk opplevelse</li>
            </ul>    
        </div>
        
        <div class="aside2">
            <h3>Prosjektype:</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Byplan</li>
                <li>Parker og byrom </li>
                <li>Bolig</li>
                <li>Næring</li>
                .........
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="picture_box">
            <img src=""/>
            <h3>Green House D36</h3>
            <div class="icons">
                <h4>1</h4>
                <h4>2</h4>
                <h4>3</h4>
                <h4>4</h4>
                <h4>5</h4>
                <h4>6</h4>
                <h4>7</h4>
                <h4>8</h4> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Putting my SCSS code under here:**

```
.container{
    margin-top: 5em;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, [col] 150px ) ;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, [row] auto  );
    justify-content: space-evenly;


    img{
        max-width: 300px;
        height: auto;
    }

    .headline1{
        grid-row: row; 
        grid-column: col / span 1;
    }

    .headline2{
        grid-row: row;
        grid-column: col 3/ span 2;
    }

    .aside_container{
        grid-column: col / span 2;
        grid-row: row 2;
        display: grid;

        .aside1 {
            ul{
            } 
        }

        .aside2{
            ul{
            }
        }
    }

    .main{
        grid-column: col 3 / span 2;
        grid-row: row 2;

        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 0.5em;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
         
        .picture_box{
 
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seem to fit the question, giving this js fiddle
`https://jsfiddle.net/63oLenas/`
everything works fine.

Maybe the empty img element here is causing the issue:

```
 <div class="picture_box">
        <img src=""/>
        <h3>Green House D36</h3>
```

Comment: The empty image box, is not empty. I just removed it, when I posted this. But I can se that it works fine on jsfiddel. Strange. Mabye it's somewhere else in my code that makes it behave like this.

Comment: Thank u for checking it out :)